# Format disk as MBR on a notebook with BIOS,

Tags: windows, installation, bios, mbr, gpt

I have an Asus X55A notebook that I'm replacing hdd with an ssd and clean installing Win 10.

I'm pretty sure the X55A uses the older legacy bios so I have to format the ssd as MBR correct? BIOS cannot boot GPT disks is that correct?

Comment: Windows does the right thing automatically though...?

Comment: Hi, I've been informed by a Tom's Hardware member that this notebook's particular bios does support UEFI and apparently that most OEM notebook's that come pre-installed with Win 8 usually come formatted using GPT... And yes apparently Win 10 should insist on formatting using GPT...